# Huge font in HTML email for Outlook

Tags: html, email, fonts, outlook, size

I'm designing an email newsletter in [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) for multiple email clients. So far it works in every client except for [Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook)...

The font gets so large that the tables, etc. break. I've already given the [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) inline everywhere and added some CSS tricks for Outlook. I'm out of solutions for this one.
This is the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=600,initial-scale = 2.3,user-scalable=no">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Client-specific Styles */
            #outlook a{padding:0;}

            body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;}

            body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}

            p {
                margin: 1em 0;
            }

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                color: black !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
            }

            h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
                color: blue !important;
            }

            h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active {
                color: red !important;
            }

            h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited {
                color: purple !important;
            }

            table td {
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            .yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span { color: black; text-decoration: none !important; border-bottom: none !important; background: none !important;}

            .ExternalClass {
                width:                        100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
                line-height:                 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass{display:inline-block; line-height: 131%};
            .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
            .ReadMsgBody{width: 100%;}
            table td {
                border-collapse:            collapse;
            }
            body {
                margin:                         0;
                padding:                        0;
                width:                       100%;
                overflow-y:                hidden;
                background-color:         #000000;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust:    100%;
                -ms-text-size-adjust:        100%;
                font-family:            Helvetica;
                vertical-align:               top;
                border-spacing:               0px;
                color:                    #ffffff;
            }
            p {
                margin-bottom:               10px;
                margin-left:                 35px;
                margin-right:                35px;
            }
            .container {
                width:                      600px;
                background-color:            #000;
                margin:                    0 auto;
            }
            a:link {
                color:                    #ffffff;
                text-decoration:        underline;
            }
            a:visited {
                color:                    #6E6C64;
                text-decoration:        underline;
            }
            a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
                text-decoration:             none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" style="overflow-y:hidden; background-color:#000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;  font-family:Helvetica; vertical-align:top; border-spacing:0px; font-size:1em;">
        <table class="container" width="600px" background-color="#000000" margin="0 auto" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr width="600px">
                <td style="line-height:10px;" width="600px"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/header.png" align="absbottom"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#f8f8f8" width="600px">
                <td style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;" width="600px">
                    <h1 align="center" style="color:#000000;">Need apps? We build ‘em.</h1>

                    <p style="margin-bottom:10px; color:#575757; margin-left:35px; margin-right:35px; font-size:1em;">Het gebruik van applicaties, oftewel apps, is namelijk booming! Steeds meer merken en bedrijven zien het gemak van een app in. Het is de ideale optie voor het versterken van uw merk, zowel extern als intern, of het opzetten van een geheel nieuw product. Ook de enorme groei in gebruik van mobiele apparaten zorgt er voor dat een sterk merk niet meer kan achter blijven.</p>

                    <p style="margin-bottom:10px; color:#575757; margin-left:35px; margin-right:35px; font-size:1em;">Mocht u geïnteresseerd zijn in onze service, van op maat gemaakte applicaties en backend oplossingen, neem dan gerust contact met ons op. U bent van harte welkom voor een kop koffie bij ons in de Suikersilo's, tijdens een verkennend gesprek of een demonstratie van de mogelijkheden van apps voor mobiel, tablets, tv en het web.</p>

                    <p style="margin-bottom:10px; color:#575757; margin-left:35px; margin-right:35px; margin-bottom:60px; font-size:1em;">Alvast bedankt en hopelijk tot ziens.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="600px">
                <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/title.png" align="absbottom"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#232323" width="600px">
                <td style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;">
                    <table height="auto" border="0" cellpadding="5px" margin-top="0" align="center" style="color:#fff;">
                        <tr align="center">
                        <td align="center"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/apple.png"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/android.png"  /></td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;">Apple iOS de kracht achter<br />
                          de iPhone, iPod en iPad.</td>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;">Android is met Google, HTC en<br />
                                            Samsung, het meest gebruikte<br />
                                            mobiele besturingssysteem.</td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/windows.png" /></td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/html.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;">Microsoft en Nokia bieden<br />
                          samen de Windows Phone, <br />
                          voor de conventionele liefhebbers.</td>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;">Ook een mobiele web app<br />
                          in HTML5 en CSS3<br />
                          is geen probleem!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="600px">
                <td><img src="http://mediabunker.com/email/actie.png" align="absbottom"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr width="600px">
                <td>
                    <table border="0" HALIGN="center" style="margin-bottom:30px; margin-top:20px;">
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="center" width="189px" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;"><font color="white">Suikersilo-West 23 <br />1165 MP Halfweg</font></td>
                        <td align="center" width="189px" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;"><a href="tel:0031238200140">Tel +31 23 820 0140</a><br> <a href="mailto:info@mediabunker.com">info@mediabunker.com</a></td>
                        <td align="center" width="189px" style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:1em;"><a href="http://mediabunker.com">www.mediabunker.com</a><br> <a href="http://twitter.com/mediabunker">twitter.com/mediabunker</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the online version [FWIW](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FWIW); http://mediabunker.com/email/email.html. And a quick upload of a screenshot someone sent me, this is the newest Outlook version I think.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the widths on the TD not the TR and ensuring the table has a width set.

Comment: Have you tried setting absolute font-sizes on the table cells? 1em can mean anything – based on the rendering engines defaults.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help either, thanks for the try though.

Answer (score 1):

First up: It's not a good idea to use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) classes when sending out [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) emails. They will be stripped or ignored in many clients, including Outlook.

Concerning your problem: To me it looks like the width of the `td`'s aren't set properly.
When I look into your source code you define the width of the table, `tr`'s and `td`'s as follows.

```
width="600px"
```

This should be

```
width="600"
```

instead. More importantly, however, (since Outlook likes to ignore HTML attributes on tables sometimes) add inline CSS to your elements like this:

```
style="width: 600px"
```

Don't forget the table cells (`td`) and the parent table.

I think that should do.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Do not use header tags in an HTML email.  Some clients will wreck havoc on your styling with header tags regardless of how you declare it.

1. Remove the h1 tag
2. Remove all your styling from the TR tag surrounding the text your having trouble with and place that styling in the td tag instead.
3. Remove the width around that element completely and replace it with text-align.

Long answer:

1. Use depreciated HTML tags whereever possible instead of CSS.

   1. body bgcolor="" instead of style="background-color..
   2. td margin="0" instead of margin="0 auto" (better off.. use cellpadding instead)
2. Fix

   1. width="5px"  .. do not write px in depreciated html dimensions (same goes for cellpadding)
   2. margin="0 auto" .. do not use shorthand code
   3. line-height .. do not use line-height unless you're using it purely for styling, if you're using it for proper formatting.. don't count on it working.
   4. h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 .. don't use them.
   5. p .. don't use paragraphs, put your style in the td and wrap each paragraph in a td instead of a p.

Replace all your head CSS as far down as your body tag with this code, and if you think you need to add more CSS to the head, don't.  Not until you're far more proficient.  This should help you out..

```
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Client-specific Styles */
        html>body {width:100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
        body, div, p, a, li, td{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}
        .ReadMsgBody, .ExternalClass {width: 100% !important;background-color:#ffffff;}
        .ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%} 
        #outlook a {padding:0;}
        table { border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
        table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
        img {outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display:block;}
        a img{border:none;}
        p{margin: 1em 0;}
        a {color:#ffffff;}
        a:link{color:#ffffff;}
        a:visited{color:#ffffff;}
        a:hover{color:#ffffff;}
        .yshortcuts a { border-bottom: none !important;}

    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;color:#252525;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;" border="0">
```